# When is it more efficient to use CORDIC or a polynomial approximation?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, assembly, floating-point

I am working on an architecture which does not feature floating point hardware, but only a 16 bit ALU and a 40 bit MAC.

I have already implemented 32-bit single precision floating point addition/subtraction, multiplication, cosine, sine, division, square root, and range reduction all in software on this architecture.

To implement cosine and sine I first used range reduction using the method described in the paper ["ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS" by K.C. NG](http://www.derekroconnor.net/Software/Ng--ArgReduction.pdf)
I then implemented a cosine and sine function which are polynomial approximations to the cosine and sine functions on the range -pi/4 to +pi/4. I referred to the book "Computer Approximations", Hart, et al. for the polynomials.

I have also heard that I should consider the CORDIC algorithm.  However, I was wondering if anyone knows if it would be more or less efficient (in terms of throughput, memory overhead, and number of instructions required) than the method I already used?  I have implemented my software functions on a multicore architecture where each core features only 128 words of instruction memory and a 128 word 16-bit data memory.
Also I have tried searching for how to implement the CORDIC algorithm for cosine and sine, but I couldn't find any good resources for 32-bit floating point implementations.  Does anybody have suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a performance problem with your existing implementation?

Comment: The performance is pretty slow.  Also I am going to compare my software implementations versus if I had a hardware floating-point multiplier or adder or both available to me.  One question I have always had on my mind is, well what about CORDIC, and how does it come into play here?  Should I disregard it as an option? Why?  I haven't been able to find any good resources to answer this question for 32-bit floating point.

Comment: Did you use Horner to evaluate the polynomials ? Which degree polynomials did you use ?

Comment: My sine equation is of the form ax+bx^3+cx^5+dx^7. My cosine equation is of the form a+bx^2+cx^4+dx^6.  I am not sure what you mean by using Horner? I found the coefficients a, b, c, and d by using the Computer Approximations book.  I used a polynomial which guarantees me accuracy to 24 bits.

Comment: For [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) compute a+x*(b+x*(c+x*d)) for cos and similar for sin.  Note, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC#Hardware) says  “when a hardware multiplier is available (e.g., in a DSP microprocessor), table-lookup methods and power series are generally faster than CORDIC”.

Comment: It all depends on how much precision you need. For example, if you do not need precision beyond 1/32768, a simple lookup table with an array of Ints might do the trick (much less memory used than a full polynomial approximation algorithm. On the other hand, if you need one billion decimals, regardless of the argument (like sin x when x is very close to 0), you cannot use an arbitrary Nth degree polynomial, you will have to iterate until you get the needed precision. Start there, evaluate your needs, then implement different algorithms and compare your results.

Comment: @jwpat7, I didn't implement horner's method. I split things apart a little differently and reduced my number of cores from 10 to 9. I do have a hardware multiplier. What is weird about the wikipedia article is that they have a cordic implementation example that uses multiplication.

Comment: @wldsvc, I need precision out to 2^-23.  I already know that degree polynomial I needed since my input range is restricted to -pi/4 to +pi/4. I listed my polynomial above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CORDIC gives you one bit per loop iteration, so implementing it in software will likely be slower than your polynomial version.  That may also be why it is hard to find articles on software implementations of CORDIC:  its performance is inferior, so nobody bothers.

Re your comment:  [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) is the practice of evaluating polynomials from highest-order coefficient to lowest, by repeatedly adding the coefficient, then multiplying by the variable `x`.  In contrast, the naive method (i.e., evaluating the powers of `x` first, then multiplying them by their coefficients and adding them together) takes more work and can be less numerically stable than Horner's method.

You haven't mentioned exactly how you're trying to evaluate your polynomials, so I will suggest a formula:

```
x2 = x * x
cos = ((COS_D * x2 + COS_C) * x2 + COS_B) * x2 + COS_A
sin = (((SIN_D * x2 + SIN_C) * x2 + SIN_B) * x2 + SIN_A) * x
```

Note that you can get better precision if you adapt your constants to the range over which you are evaluating the function, rather than using the Taylor coefficients.  (Again, apologies if you have done some or all of these things, but you didn't mention what you had already tried...)

---

This is probably less relevant for your case (which presumably has just a 16x16-bit MAC), but if your processor can launch multiple arithmetic evaluations at once, you may be able to get better performance if you write your evaluation in a tree-like form, avoiding some of the sequential dependency of operations:

```
x2 = x * x
x4 = x2 * x2
cos = (COS_D * x2 + COS_C) * x4 + (COS_B * x2 + COS_A)
sin = ((SIN_D * x2 + SIN_C) * x4 + (SIN_B * x2 + SIN_A)) * x
```

If your processor has a vector ALU, this formula also suggests a productive use for it...

Comment: FWIW, your second evaluation scheme is called Estrin's method.

Comment: BTW, I highly recommend the book referenced in the wikipedia article on Estrin's method:  _Elementary Functions: Algorithms And Implementation_, by Jean-Michel Muller

Comment: @comingstorm, Horner's method would probably have provided me with higher throughput however and an easier to understand datapath.

Comment: @comingstorm, For sine, I used a polynomial ax+bx^3+cs^5+dx^7.  I multiplied the input by 4/pi (takes 1 core) since my range reduction algorithm reduces the range between -pi/4 and +pi/4 but my polynomial operates between [0,1]. I used this value in another core to create x^3, x^5, and x^7. These first two cores send their results to another core to create ax, bx^3, cx^5, and dx^7.  These results are sent to a series of adder cores (1 add requires two cores) to create ax+bx^3, then ax+bx^3+cx^5, then ax+bx^3+cx^5+dx^7.  This requires 8 cores (ignore *4/pi). Horner's method requires 10 cores.

Comment: Basically it was area versus throughput.  I was worried about running out of cores, so I reduced the area as much as possible.

Comment: @comingstorm, Estrin's method would require 12 cores.  However, I could see both working well in a FMA architecture.

Comment: Also, I don't have a vector ALU.

Answer (score 3):

If the MAC is significantly faster than an equivalent sequence of shifts and ands and adds, use a polynomial; don't even consider CORDIC (except possibly for a single step or two of range reduction).  It's hard to find FP CORDIC algorithms precisely because that criteria always holds for any system where FP is used (in the past ~35 years), so CORDIC isn't considered.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of analysis I was looking for.

Comment: what about this paper? http://www.acsel-lab.com/arithmetic/papers/ARITH11/ARITH11_Hekstra.pdf